The sharing of energy between beta particle and its neutrino

the answer to this is that the KE is constant, and that beta has a continuous range of energy. I understand that the energy in beta particle decay is distributed between the neutrino and the beta particle, but shouldn't the KE of all the particles as in the addition of KE of Beta particle and neutrino together remain constant, even for beta decay? so how is this graph relevant?

The x-axis is labelled the kinetic energy of emitted particles which is to be read as the kinetic energy of each of the individual emitted particles not the sum of the kinetic energy of all of the emitted particles.

Ok that makes sense. Also why would it be constant for a particles if for example the KE is distributed between the alpha particle and the daughter product?

@Safayousif Because the alpha emission is a two product particles (alpha and daughter nucleus) decay rather than the three particles (beta, neutrino and daughter nucleus) decay.

I still dont understand why thats a reason? Do you mean that if its 2 products the energy gets split equally?

With two products the law of conservation of momentum tells you that there is only one way to split the momentum and hence the energy. This is not the case with three products.

Ok that makes sense thank you.
